# Want to print the positional argument with variable substitution

Tags: shell-script

`$var` has the position of positional argument and want to substitute & print the positional argument.

```
/home/yeshky>echo $1 
/home/yeshky>abc
/home/yeshky>var=1
/home/yeshky>echo "You have opted for $`$var`"
```

Expected Result: `/home/yeshky>You have opted for abc`

====Have tried substituting the below but no luck:

```
echo "You have opted for $$((var))"
echo "You have opted for $($((var)))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is indirection.  In `bash` and some other shells you can do

```
printf '%s\n' "${!var}"
```

to print the value of the variable whose name is stored in the variable `var`

You have to use the braces to access the variable to do this, and the first character inside the brace has to be `!`.  Then the rest is the name of the variable that contains the name of the variable you want to retrieve.

For lots more on the subject see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) especially, of course, the section on indirection